# How to loop through indices in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to run a for loop in python that looks like this:

```
data = np.linspace(0.5, 50, 10)

output = []
for i in data:
  x = data[i] - data[i+1]
  output.append(data)
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

For reference I want the code to do the following:

- x1 = x = data[0] - data[1]
- x2 = x = data[1] - data[2] ...

and output it to the list.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `for i in data` loops over the elements. You probably want `for i,el in enumerate(data)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

- You are iterating over the actual elements, not their index. To iterate over the indexes you can do something like this `for index in range(len(data) - 1))`.
- As shown above, you want to iterrate until `len(data) - 1` in order to avoid getting out of bounds.
- It seems that you are calculating `x` but eventually append `data` instead.
- To achive readable code, it is important to give variables meaningful names (`i` and `x` are not meaningfull).

```
data = np.linspace(0.5, 50, 10)

output = []
for index in range(len(data) - 1):
  result = data[index] - data[index + 1]
  output.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in data:` loops directly over `data`, thus `i` will be each element in `data`, not its index. If you need the index, use `enumerate()`:

```
output = []
for i, elem in enumerate(data):
  x = data[i] - data[i+1]
  output.append(data)
```

However, that won't work, due to an out-of-bounds error that will occur at the very end. Instead, you can use built-in numpy functionality:

```
output = data[:-1] - data[1:]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
array([-5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5])
```

Or possible solutions:

```
np.full(9, -5.5)
```

```
np.ones(9) * -5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to calculate the successive differences, but reversed. You can use [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

```
np.diff(data[::-1])[::-1]
```

Other option, shift the array by taking a slice of all but the last/first element and subtract:

```
data[:-1] - data[1:]
```

Output: `array([-5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5, -5.5])`